# (PHP/Postgresql) Call a function which returns void?

Tags: php, html, postgresql, web

I'm getting crazy trying to call, inside PHP code, a function that returns void, with pg_prepare/pg__execute...

```
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "",'SELECT * FROM dungeonasdb.crea_personaggio( "$nome", "$descrizione", "$email", "$password")');
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "", NULL ) or die('Query creazione fallita');
```

Is there any settings of pg_prepare/pg_execute that I do wrong?
Thanks

Comment: `dungeonasdb.crea_personaggio` is your table name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to do something different:

[`pg_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php): don't put specific values, but placeholders. You will bind them to values later on. I prefer to always give statements a name.

If `dungeonasdb.crea_personaggio` is the function that returns `void`, you can call  it by means of:

```
SELECT dungeonasdb.crea_personaggio(...)
```

You cannot call your function by means of `SELECT * FROM dungeonasdb.crea_personaggio(...)` because this would imply that `dungeonasdb.crea_personaggio` is a [*set returning function*](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Return_more_than_one_row_of_data_from_PL/pgSQL_functions), which is not.

So you probably want your statements to be:

```
$result = pg_prepare($dbconn, "crea_personnagio", 
   'SELECT dungeonasdb.crea_personaggio($1, $2, $3, $4)'); 
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "crea_personnagio", 
    ARRAY($nome, $descrizione, $email, $password)) 
    or die('Query execuzione fallita');
```

Your second statment is a [`pg_execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php) statement that *binds* parameters to the placedholders (`$1`, ...), and executes.

Comment: ok I solved the problem, it was the function in the database, I wrote all the functions using only the tables name  and not like  'dbname.tablename'  .
Also I think your answer it's not correct, beacause PERFORM works only inside postgresql functions , you can't use it from outside. 
But thanks for your time :)

Comment: You're right about `PERFORM`. I've corrected it. In PostgreSQL, what you're actually writing is  `schema_name.function_name(...)` or `schema_name.table_name` (or, in general `schema_name.object_name`). You don't access two databases from the same connection (except through FDW). In PostgreSQL you have *database -> schema -> object*. In MySQL (for instance), you have only *database (=schema) -> object*.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If so, it is customary to mark it as *accepted*, so that people can concentrate on the *unanswered* ones.

Comment: I haven't used your method but it works the same, now I accept it, thanks again!